# How can I create a new table in SQL Server CE for Windows phone 8 c#

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I want to create new table at runtime but I don't know how to do this.

When I want to insert to database when I haven't for example `Person` table I've got this error

> The specified table does not exist

It's completely logical this table doesn't exist, now I have to create this table at runtime and I don't know how?

Comment: any tries so far ? if so please update with question

Answer (score 0):

You must use the DatabaseSchemaUpdater class, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394018(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I read this before but I didn't get anything of this and I don't know how use their ideas